# Polybar doesn't appear in x2go sessions

Tags: x11, panel, x2go

When I run `polybar example -l trace` on the remote side (in both Qtile and MATE), nothing appears and the output is:

```
* Loading config: /home/cyber/.config/polybar/config
- config: Copying missing params (sub="module/backlight-acpi", base="module/xbacklight")
- config: Current bar section: [bar/example]
warn: No monitor specified, using "default"
* Loaded monitor default (1024x768+0+0)
* Bar geometry: 1024x35+0+0
- bar: Attach X event sink
- bar: Attach signal receiver
- controller: Install signal handler
- controller: Setup user-defined modules
- module/bspwm: Deconstructing
error: Disabling module "bspwm" (reason: Could not find socket: /tmp/bspwm_50_0-socket)
error: module/xbacklight: Could not get data (err: XCB_NAME (15))
- module/xbacklight: Deconstructing
error: Disabling module "xbacklight" (reason: Not supported for "default")
- pulseaudio: started mainloop
warn: pulseaudio: using default sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo
- module/wlan: Deconstructing
error: Disabling module "wlan" (reason: Invalid network interface "net1")
- module/battery: Deconstructing
error: Disabling module "battery" (reason: No suitable way to get current charge state)
- module/temperature: Deconstructing
error: Disabling module "temperature" (reason: The file '/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp' does not exist)
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level 0
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level item 0
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level item 1
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level 1
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level item 0
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level item 1
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level 2
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level item 0
- module/powermenu: Creating menu level item 1
* Starting application
- controller: Main thread id = 1
* Starting module/filesystem
* Starting module/alsa
- module/filesystem: Thread id = 2
* Starting module/pulseaudio
* Starting module/xkeyboard
- module/alsa: Thread id = 3
* Starting module/memory
* Starting module/cpu
- module/xkeyboard: Thread id = 5
- module/pulseaudio: Thread id = 4
* Starting module/eth
- module/cpu: Thread id = 6
* Starting module/date
- module/memory: Thread id = 7
* Starting module/powermenu
- module/eth: Thread id = 8
- module/date: Thread id = 9
- module/powermenu: Thread id = 10
* Entering event loop (thread-id=1)
warn: module/eth: Failed to query interface 'sit0'
* Eventqueue worker (thread-id=11)
- bar: Create renderer
- renderer: Get TrueColor visual
- renderer: Allocate colormap
- renderer: Allocate output window
```

`polybar -vvv` prints:

```
polybar 3.2.1

Features: +alsa +curl -i3 -mpd +network +pulseaudio +xkeyboard

X extensions: +randr (+monitors) -render -damage -sync -composite +xkb +xrm +xcursor

Build type: Gentoo
Compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++
Compiler flags: -march=bdver2 -O2 -pipe -w -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-noexcept-type -O2 -pedantic -pedantic-errors
Linker flags: -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed
```

The bar launches on the local side with X11 forwarding.

Also it seems somebody had [the same problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/88ixug/i3_x2go_polybar_st/) too.

Comment: That may happen because x2go doesn't support the Composite extension...

Comment: Cyber Tailor: If you update to polybar 3.3.0, polybar will tell you if you don't have xcomposite enabled. 3.2.1 unfortunately still silently fails.